# Call to a member function getElementById() on a non-object

Tags: php, dom, curl

I'm developing a script to obtain some elements of a website with cURL in POO of PHP5, this is my code:

```
class obtain{
    protected $url;
    private $handler;
    protected $response;

    function __construct($url){
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    protected function curl(){
        $this->handler  = curl_init($this->url);
        curl_setopt($this->handler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $this->response = curl_exec($this->handler);
        curl_close($this->handler);
        return $this->response;
    }
}

class page extends obtain{
    private $reponse;
    private $dom;

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct('http://www.page.com');
        $this->response = parent::curl();
        $this->dom      = new DOMDocument();
        $this->dom      = $this->dom->loadHTML($this->response);
        var_dump($this->dom->getElementById('contenido-portada'));
    }
}

new page();
```

I get this error when I run it:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementById() on a non-object in...

Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Because `$this->dom` is not an object, apparently. Why don't you `var_dump` it instead?

Comment: POO? My favorite PHP feature

Comment: which line are you getting the error? at `$this->dom` or at `var_dump`? @AaronW. POO is the spanish translation to OOP. -> Programación Orientada a Objetos. lol

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán interesting - never knew that...I'm never calling it OOP again now.

Comment: @AaronW. -What do you use to program? -Poo, just Poo.

Comment: @AaronW. POO is the spanish translation, SergiCastellsaguéMillán has reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
$this->dom      = $this->dom->loadHTML($this->response);
```

You're loading the HTML, using `loadHTML`; but you're assigning the value back to `$this->dom`. `loadHTML` returns a boolean depending on whether it works or not, so you're over-writing your existing object.

You should probably do something like:

```
if (! $this->dom->loadHTML($this->response)) {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, It must be:   $this->dom->loadHTML($this->response);   if I put $this->dom      = $this->dom->loadHTML($this->response); I'm overwriting with a boolean

Answer (score 2):

Don't assign the result of `$this->dom->loadHTML($this->response)` back to `$this->dom` (as the return value is a boolean).

However, you may want to use this boolean value to ensure that the HTML was unserialised correctly.

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).